# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\ln(2x)}{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was attempting to find the indefinite integral I below via differentiation under the integral sign technique.

$$I=\int\frac{\ln{2x}}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
let us introduce the parameter $t$: 
$$I(t)=\int\frac{\ln{xt}}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
taking the partial derivative with respect to $t$, we get:
$$I'(t)=\int\frac{1}{t(x^2+1)}\,dx$$
then taking the antiderivative of the RHS, we get 
$$I'(t)=\frac{1}{t}\arctan{x}$$
Finally integrating both sides with respect to $t$, we get 
$$I(t)=\ln{t}\arctan{x}$$
since in our original integral $t=2, I(2)$ will be the solution.
However, $$I(2)=\ln{2}\arctan{x}$$ which is clearly not right. Could anyone point out the mistake or false assumption I made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you went from

$$I'(t)=\frac{1}{t}\arctan{x} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

to

$$I(t)=\ln{t}\arctan{x} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

you forgot to include a constant relative to $t$, but which could depend on $x$, so call it $C(x)$. Thus, the proper equation in \eqref{eq2A} would be

$$I(t) = \ln{t}\arctan{x} + C(x) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

From the original integral, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
I & =\int\frac{\ln(2x)}{x^2+1}\,dx \\
& = \int\frac{\ln(2) + \ln(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx \\
& = \int\frac{\ln(2)}{x^2+1}\,dx + \int\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx \\
& = \ln(2)\arctan(x) + \int\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, you have

$$C(x) = \int\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Comment: interesting, so would ln(2)\arctanx+ C(x) be the solution to the indefinite integral? Additionally, I tried computing the definite integral from 0 to 1 with the same integrand. Using a calculator it returns: ~
-0.371570, while using my solution, the answer is ln(2)arctan1, which is roughly 0.54440. shouldn't putting bounds to the integral eliminate the arbitrary function C(x)?
Edit: didn't see your edit.

Comment: @Gabriel Actually, since the bounds would be for the value being integrated, i.e., $x$, then it wouldn't eliminate the arbitrary function $C(x)$. Instead, the bounds would apply to both the $\arctan(x)$ in the one function as well as to the other function $C(x)$ I've shown.

Comment: I see, so would It actually be possible to find an explicit function for the antiderivative or compute definite integrals of the  of lnx/(x^2+1)?

Comment: @Gabriel I just tried to do a substitution of $x = e^y$, but it didn't help much. Note I used Wolfram Alpha to try to do this, with the results shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28x%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29+dx). As you can see, there's no closed form for it as such, as it uses the $L_2$ function, that is called the "polylogarithm" function.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going here.. one could very well state from the start that $\ln(tx)=\ln t+\ln x$ thus $$I(t)=\ln t \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\int \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\ln t \arctan x+C(x)$$
The differentiation seems part seems useless.

Comment: @Gabriel What do you really want to achieve with this problem? Or what is the original problem? There's no closed form in terms of elementary functions, but you can use some special functions. Start with integration by parts then:
$$C(x)=\int \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\ln x\arctan x-\int \frac{\arctan x}{x}dx=\ln x\arctan x-\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)+C$$
See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) about the inverse tangent integral, but I doubt this result is useful.. So perhaps an answer to one of my two questions can help.

Comment: @Zacky I was just practicing various integration techniques and constructing integrals and came across the integral in question.

Answer (score 2):

$\int\frac{dt}{t}=\ln(t)+c=\ln(at)$.  So $I(2)=\ln(2a)\arctan(x)$.

Comment: What is $a$ there? $I(2)=\int \frac{\ln(2x)}{1+x^2}dx$ so I'm not sure how you obtain $\frac{\ln(2x)}{1+x^2}$ when you differentiate the obtained result.

Comment: a is an arbitrary constant, in relation to t.  However it can be a function of x